# ASP.Net Formview C#/SQL datatype conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, type-conversion

I have a formview that I'm populating an ID.  The ID datatype from my SQL database is nvarchar(30).  In my html markup, the parameter for ID in my formveiw block shows as string.  My ID can consist of letters, numbers, or both.  No matter if I put all characters, all numbers, or a mix, when I run the program, I get a "Error converting data type nvarchar to int." Error.  How should I change my ID dataype in either from C# side or SQL side?

Comment: Pretty difficult to help if we can't see the **relevant** code you're using.  My guess is that somewhere you're telling the code that it should be dealing with an `int`, but exactly where is a tad tricky to determine via telepathy

Comment: Why not check if it's an `int` datatype using reflection and then convert if needed? Or just make the datatype a `string` and covert to an int using I think `TryParse`?

Comment: I asked this question a bit too soon.  It wasn't in the code.  I overlooked my stored procedure I use for inserting from a formview.  I had ID as int, (@ID int) changed it to varchar(30) and it worked.